# How would I structure types to represent this?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say I have an interface

```js
interface FooBranchState {
  a: string;
  b: FooDiscriminator;
}

type FooDiscriminator = (value: any) => FooState;
```

I want to define `FooState` to be a type or interface representing the following:

- null
- an instance of `SingleFooBranchStateImpl`
- an array of instances of `SingleFooBranchStateImpl`

and also

- a function returning any of the above
- a function returning a promise to any of the above

I've currently got

```js
export type FooState = FooEndState | FooBranchState

export type FooDiscriminator = (value: any) => FooState;

export type FooEndState = null;

export type FooBranchState = SingleFooBranchState | (SingleFooBranchState[])

export interface SingleFooBranchStateImpl {
  foo: any;
  next: FooDiscriminator;
}

export type SingleFooBranchStateFunction = () => SingleFooBranchStateImpl 
export type SingleFooBranchState = SingleFooBranchStateImpl | SingleFooBranchStateFunction;


function test(value: FooState) {
  console.log(value);
}

function getSingle(): FooState {
  return { 
    foo: 1,
    next: () => null
  };
}

function getNull(): FooState {
  return null;
}


function getArray(): FooState {
  return [
    getSingle(),
    getSingle()
  ];
}

function getFunctionSingle(): FooState {
  return () => ({
    foo: 2,
    next: () => null
  });
}

function getFunctionArray(): FooState {
  return () => ([{
    foo: 3,
    next: () => null
  }]);
}

function getPromise(): FooState {
  return Promise.resolve({
    foo: 4,
    next: () => null
  });
}
```

But assigning a `FooState[]` to `FooState` requires a cast to `FooState`, otherwise I get the below error. This makes me think there's something incorrect in my definition.

The error is:

> Type 'FooBranchState[]' is not assignable to type 'FooBranchState'.
>     Type 'FooBranchState[]' is not assignable to type 'SingleFooBranchState[]'.
>       Type 'FooBranchState' is not assignable to type 'SingleFooBranchState'.
>         Type 'SingleFooBranchState[]' is not assignable to type 'SingleFooBranchState'.
>           Type 'SingleFooBranchState[]' is not assignable to type 'SingleFooBranchStateFunction'.
>             Type 'SingleFooBranchState[]' provides no match for the signature '(): SingleFooBranchStateImpl'.

edit:
corrected some typos in the original question (I was simplifying my actual code to a condensed example and made a couple errors).

As requested, here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xyag2s

edit2: 
Based on some of the comments on this, I have thought about this a little harder and came up with a more distilled example:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogtmUUC8UB2BXANlg3AWAChRIoANAJhSgGdgAnASzQHMDjxozrKoAfchQDaAXX6wEodkSIAzDGgDGwRgHs0UFhGABlZiywQAFAEoAXOSgBvKAHpbUAO6r6AaxpEoUetoz0NAOQAFowB7AC+MoTySirqmtoActhYphbcNvZOLu6e3r7+6CkRUTHKahpawACC9PQAhiBpljZ2DhB1LgA0UABGEIr1GDRcUIMa-UU4Pb0YwIJj9WgB85OYOHk+wH4aQl77B4deWdzjfdBLUPV1jVCqsoIzc1caZKLZ2AAmV1g0qmPqYD1Zh5LxVPSsQymI6HLJ7dZYHoBOhMVgBKAiPIiEqEOQKcrxKq1BogCjNDJtbJuDyELxbHZQIQrCB0ALYojhIA

```js
type Empty = null;
type X2 = string;
type X = X2 | X2[] | Empty;


function getSingle(): X { // works
  return 'hi';
}

function getNull(): X { // works
  return null;
}

function getArray(): X {  // error, because X can be null, but X2 can't be null
  return [                // X can be an array of X2, but an X[] would also contain
    getSingle()           // [ null, 'string' ]
  ];
}

function getArray2(): X { // works
  return ['test'];
}
```

In the simple example, it almost makes sense to declare getSingle as an `X2`, but for my actual needs, I need to be able to return multiple variants from the same function.

Comment: "[...] a type or interface representing the following: [...]
an instance of Foo". I don't see any type called `Foo` at all in your code.

Comment: Please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [ask] a good question.  Right now the code causing the error is missing, so I'm not sure what the problem is.  Or rather, I understand that you can't assign a `FooState[]` value to a variable of type `FooState`, but that error is consistent both with your code and the description of it.  I don't know what "an instance of Foo" is, either, so that might be part of it.  Anyway, an example that lets others easily demonstrate your issue (and only your issue) would help.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz please see my edit. I provided an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xyag2s

Comment: Links to code are great but the code should also be in the question itself.  (See [ask], "Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time")

Comment: I'm also not sure how to interpret "I want to define `FooState` to be a type ...  representing ... an instance of `FooState`".  What does that mean?

Comment: Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7-Beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJTiBALZBvZGAeyIC5kQBXAWwCNoBuCiADzHIBFgBnBKJgL4BYAFBgAngAcUXXlGQBeZAAoAbnAA2lCOUziAlIoB8yAMpg4kBqInSzFyIoqUNG5AB80GLLk-nLEADaALoeKsqGCib+kIaeyhHGyAAKUETUPBAAPDEQRvrWIqIwlFhgwEQgyNwgAOYaEeS5+MhQEGCUUFUExGTIAIwANMxs5IlRzq7IAoKixaUI5ZUUro32AS1tHV2TGrNFIiVlFVVwUFBrzQRbnVWBNfURww8N+sH788fLMKZ1r00OFDXdq3FSREzKHokcgAJmGIFY7DBSSoUwEBWmc0OCyWVRgAEFzpdAZsQTtxiZAlC+gBmeGIsbg3bTd6Yg4AenZyAAJkQIDUAORgZAAdyIUAA1sh6Ag4JRuChgMKbl1uMg4MhJGkMgr4URhRqYFUVSBQLV1ZrtZlPosTpb0sSNsDtlVUulMgA6NrcIgaVQQSGEaHIAAs9NGyImqLc6I+IiAA) maybe?

Comment: I've updated the example again. Thanks for your help. Sorry, it's been an error prone process to match the example code against the more brief description. `FooState` should be an instance of `SingleFooBranchStateImpl`, which defined the base type.

Also, the link you provided has a compile error too.

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like:

```
export type Foo = any;

export type FooState = null | Foo | Array<Foo> | FooDistriminator | FooDistriminatorPromise;

export type FooDistriminator = (value: any) => null | Foo | Array<Foo>;

export type FooDistriminatorPromise = (value: any) => Promise<null | Foo | Array<Foo>>;
```

Edit: In your stackblitz problem seems to be with your function typings for passed value and return value. I got it working like:

```
export type FooState = FooEndState | FooBranchState

export type FooDiscriminator = (value: any) => FooState;

export type FooEndState = null;

export type FooBranchState = SingleFooBranchState | Array<SingleFooBranchState> | Promise<SingleFooBranchStateImpl>

export interface SingleFooBranchStateImpl {
    foo: any;
    next: FooDiscriminator;
}

export type SingleFooBranchStateFunction = () => SingleFooBranchStateImpl
export type SingleFooBranchState = SingleFooBranchStateImpl | SingleFooBranchStateFunction;


function test(value: FooState) {
    console.log(value);
}

function getSingle(): SingleFooBranchStateImpl {
    return {
        foo: 1,
        next: () => null
    };
}

function getNull(): FooState {
    return null;
}


function getArray(): Array<SingleFooBranchState> {
    return [
        getSingle(),
        getSingle()
    ];
}

function getFunctionSingle(): FooState {
    return () => ({
        foo: 2,
        next: () => null
    });
}


function getPromise(): Promise<SingleFooBranchStateImpl> {
    return Promise.resolve({
        foo: 4,
        next: () => null
    });
}

test(null);
test(getSingle());
test(getNull());
test(getArray());
test(getFunctionSingle());
test(getPromise());
```

Comment: That works so long as type Foo = any, but if I try to flesh that type out, I get mostly the same errors I had before. Pleas see my edit for an example of code

Comment: I saw your update, and it looks like you're bumping into a similar problem as I did. You have to declare `getArray()` as returning an Array<SingleFooBranchState>. It seems (and what I'm trying to achieve) that FooState can be a FooBranchState, can be an Array<SingleFooBranchState>, therefore, transitively, FooState can be Array<SingleFooBranchState>, and by identity, Array<SingleFooBranchState> is a FooState. So you should be able to declare the getArray function as FooState, right?

Comment: Correct. you could replace the return value of getArray() from  Array<SingleFooBranchState> to FooState and it will successfully compile.

Comment: Not for me. It gives me a similar error as initially